# How to correctly display homepage "url" property value using Schema.org

Tags: url, schema.org, homepage, json-ld, relative-urls

How do you correctly display the `url` property value of your website's landing page?

Do I need to specify the full name like `"www.example.com"` or is `"/"` sufficient?

I currently have it like this:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
     {
          "@context": "http://schema.org",
          "@graph": [{
               "@type": "Organization",
               "name": "My Website Name",
               "sameAs": [
                    "http://www.facebook.com/my_website",
                    "http://www.twitter.com/my_website",
                    "http://www.instagram.com/my_website"
               ],
               "url": "/"
          }, {
               "@type": "WebSite",
               "name": "My Website Name",
               "url": "/"
          }, {
               "@type": "WebPage",
               "name": "My Website Name",
               "url": "/"
          }]
     }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use relative URLs! The bot is extended enough to guess the absolute URL from your other declarations , like `base`, `canonical` etc. But relative URLs are the cause of calculation overhead and, finally, is an obstacle for good and fast crawling and and correct information mapping.